# NextJS IISNode: How To Deploy NextJS To IISNode Without Using Custom Server?

Tags: javascript, iis, next.js, iisnode

I want to deploy my NextJS App to IISNode, but I want to keep the SSR SSG. I do not want to use the custom server to render my app because it will remove the SSR and SSG capabilities. Is there a way to do that? What should I put inside my `web.config`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"I do not want to use the custom server to render my app because it will remove the SSR and SSG capabilities"_? In what way will the custom server remove SSR and SSG capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

> using a custom server will remove SSR and SSG functionality

I didn't completely understand your description, but I would like to share how I deployed React Next.JS on IIS.

Firstly, I need to configure the IISnode module, refer [this link](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode).

Then I run the command to build the application: `npm run build`

I refer [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) to create production application in `.next` folder.